# Breakdown parameters for the application insights

Tags: facebook, analytics

According to the Facebook documentation for the app insights ([link](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.3/app/app_insights#breakdowns)) one can specify breakdowns parameters, namely *app_event_parameter1*, *app_event_parameter2* etc. However, I failed to find any information how to do it. So, the question is where and how exactly to specify these parameters?

Answer (score 1):

The names `app_event_parameter1`, ..., `app_event_parameter10` are slightly misleading since the other breakdowns in the table are used exactly as listed.

For example, you would request the breakdowns `client` and `auth_state` like this:

```
{
    "period": "monthly",
    "breakdowns[0]": "client",
    "breakdowns[1]": "auth_state"
}
```

However, if you've been logging a custom app event with a custom parameter "game_level" then you'd request that breakdown like this:

```
{
    "period": "monthly",
    "breakdowns[0]": "game_level",
}
```

You can supply up to 10 of your own app event parameter names as breakdowns.